# DetailView class not showing data

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm using this test project to learn django, the problem is taht the view is not showing  the data, and I'm not sure how to pass the data to a detailview class

this is the model

```
class Empleado(models.Model):
    departamento = models.ForeignKey(Departamento, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    habilidades = models.ManyToManyField(Habilidad)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    antiguedad = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"nombre = {self.nombre}, fecha de nacimiento = {self.fecha_nacimiento}, antiguedad = {self.antiguedad}"
```

the view

```
class EmpladoDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Empleado
    template_name = 'empleados.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmpladoDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['titulo'] = 'Detalles Empleado'

        return context
```

and the view

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block contenido %}
<table>
    {% for empleado in lista_empleados %}
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>{{empleado.id}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>{{empleado.nombre}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Antiguedad</td>
            <td>{{empleado.antiguedad}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    
</table>
{% endblock contenido %}
```

It seems like the model data is not arriving to the view but I don't know what I missed

Comment: You’re using a DetailView but looping over a list in your template, should you be using a ListView instead?

Answer (score 0):

The spanish here throws me off a bit, but when using class based generic views, shouldn't you reference the variable "**object_list**" instead of "**lista_empleados**" (or whatever it translates to in Spanish :) )

```
{% for empleado in object_list %}
{{ empleado.id }}
        ....
{% endfor %}
```

The docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/